# How to reset number of retrys on Autosys job

Tags: autosys

I have a list of jobs that have number of retrys set on them (in jil definition). When I get the job status, I see the number of retrys (in this case 12). I am trying to find a way to reset that:

->autorep -J XXXXX%

Job Name                                                         Last Start           Last End             ST Run/Ntry Pri/Xit

---

XXXXXX                                                           03/19/2014 14:27:38  03/19/2014 14:56:07  SU 146461/12 0

Comment: Perhaps this would be better on Server Fault (http://serverfault.com/about)

Comment: Thanks. Will post there.

Answer (score 0):

number of retries could be set on a job level:
look for n_retrys: in output of command autorep -J XXXXX% -q

or it could be on server level:

## grep -i MaxRestartTrys config.$AUTOSERV

MaxRestartTrys=10

the third option is that the job was triggered manualy multiple times.

Comment: I am setting n_retrys: 15 in my job definition so I am aware of that. However, as the job runs (it runs 24 hrs a day), it occasionally fails  so after a few days, number of retries gets close to be exceeded in which case job will no longer automatically restart when it fails. I am looking for a way to reset the retry count to zero.

Comment: with every new run number, the retry number is reset to zero.